# Convert text into typographic styles (i.e text swag) programmatically

Tags: android, typography

I want to build a functionality where a submitted text/quote is output into different beautiful text designs/layouts based on predefined templates. These templates convert the user-inputted text using a combination of different fonts, varied font styles, varied sizes and in a particulat format.

There are varieties of app present on playstore or appstore which do this.

examples:
Wordswag, Typimage & Typostyle for android and 
Typorama for iphone

Can anyone help me with the logic behind this wizardry or point me towards any libraries on GitHub having similar features.

e.g.

Take the phrase "Stop hating yourself for everything you aren't and Start loving yourself for everything you already are".

Check below GIF which shows how on clicking various pattern options, the software converts the above plain text dynamically into beautiful designer text.

[image]

Comment: did u find the way to generate this?

Comment: Not really @Nick